# Why is my div covering and overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a header for my site and a left side navigation box. I have the following style code for both but for some reason I'm having two problems. 1) The nav box is overlapping onto my header slightly and 2) my header is covering up text on the website. Below is the code:

```
#nav {
border-radius: 5px;
position: fixed;
display: inline;
margin-top: 50px;
background-color: white;
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 5px;
}

#fixedheader{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
background: #000000;
padding: 3px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: you have some HTML to have the real code  to see?

Comment: You can handle your `nav` bar behind your `fixedheader` with a z-index rule. Then for your header covering text, `position: fixed;` means your header doesn't actually occupy space so it's likely to have content behind it. You can handle this with a padding on top of your page or an empty element that is the same dimensions as your header. Please post your HTML btw.

Answer (score 0):

I have no HTML so I did something fast.

1st you have to give the header an fixed height in this case I did 50px then if you want padding on the top and bottom you have to count it in the margin-top of your navbar  in this case I made the padding top and bottom 0px and the 3px only on the left and right

2nd because you nav is fixed to i did fixed it 50px from the top now if you want your margin-bottom:2px; and padding 3px you have to put top:58px; to be just under your fixedheader

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}
#nav {
border-radius: 5px;
position: fixed;
display: inline;
top: 50px;
background-color:pink;/* white;*/
color: black;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 5px;
}

#fixedheader{
  height:50px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
background:red; /* #000000;*/
padding: 0px 3px;
display: block;
/*margin-bottom: 2px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedheader">
    <p>the fixed header 50px height  the fixed header 50px height</p>
                                                    
</div>
<div id="nav">
                    <p> your nav</p>
                     <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p> <p> your nav</p>
               </div>
```

Comment: I have the code as you do above, but am still having an issue (also, I set the height: 75 for the #fixedheader otherwise the header is smaller than the image in my header). You can view the page(s) at www.brandonholmes.net/resed_net.

Comment: UPDATE: I re-read and fixed the issue, but I'm confused. Given that the #fixedheader has the display: block style, shouldn't it force the #nav element to to go below it? Why do I have to specify the top-margin from the top of the page?

Comment: Because your navbar have to be fixed ? If you want to fix something you have to give him a position where you want him to be like i did do in this link  https://jsfiddle.net/rpfbrbog/1/

Comment: To expand on that, when I add text to my page, why does that text appear underneath my  #fixedheader? Shouldn't those divs push anything else that's added to the page down the page? Or does that arrangement only occur if items are in a div?